# Trying to reverse the order of the digits in an integer, extra digits are shown

Tags: c

Firstly, this is a homework assignment, and I am very new to programming in C. What I am trying to accomplish is the user puts in an integer, and then each individual digit of that integer is printed on a new line, like below:

```
Enter integer: 1234
The digits are:
1
2
3
4
```

My problem is that whatever integer you input, for some reason a 7 and a 4 are added on to the end. Below is my code and an example of the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Success 0

int main()
{ int integer;
  int reverse;
  int digit;

  printf("Enter Integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &integer);

  /* Reverse the numbers in the integer */
  while (integer != 0) { 
    digit = integer%10;
    reverse = (reverse * 10) + digit;
    integer = integer / 10;
    }

  /* Print the numbers of the reverse integer, in reverse order */
  while (reverse != 0) {
    digit = reverse%10;
    printf("%d\n", digit);
    reverse = reverse / 10;
    }

return Success;
}
```

Example of problem:

```
Enter Integer: 12345
1
2
3
4
5
7
4
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what might cause this outcome? By printing `reverse` I have narrowed it down to a problem with the first while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse is not initialized. This means there could be any value in that variable when you start touching it. Set it to 0 after you declare it and see what happens.

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall`, the warning message would suggest this as an issue. I recommend compiling with all warnings, as it helps catch these bugs.

Comment: I was, and it didn't warn me of it, else I probably would have figured it out. As it was I think I would have been stuck on this a while, it didn't even cross my mind that there would be some random rubbish in there.

Comment: Once you get in the habit of initializing anything you declare, it will make your life a lot easier. Even old hands can make that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

One issue is that `reverse` needs to be initialized:

```
reverse = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint: are the values of `digit` and `reverse` always what you expect they should be? Try printing them out every iteration, so you can see. Or, even better, learn to use your platform's debugger and just step through it.

---

Spoiler: you'll probably get more out of solving it yourself, with the hint above.
But ... you didn't initialize `reverse` to zero before starting. That would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check the initial value of `reverse` (hint: there isn't one). Right now it's starting with garbage in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually print the int to a string and reverse that through iterating through the string in reverse order. See sprintf for details.

Answer (score 0):

I would scan the integer into a string, use the strlen function to determine its length, and then traverse it backwards.